# Stripe Replace/Override UsageRecord for subscriptionItem

Tags: stripe-payments

I have customer who subscribe to the `subscription` with `subscriptionItem` with metered usage. Follow the documentation https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing#reporting-usage and https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create
I reported usage with API call:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_items/si_xxxx/usage_records -u sk_live_xxx: -X POST   -d quantity=500 -d timestamp=1569570600
```

I have reported the wrong usage, and I want to override it. According to the documentation, I should use the same `timestamp` as the wrong record have and use `action:set` instead of default `action:increment`
So theoretically API call should look like this

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_items/si_xxxx/usage_records -u sk_live_xxx: -X POST   -d quantity=0 -d timestamp=1569570600 -d action=set
```

Unfortunately, instead of successful update, I have got below error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Usage records can only be incremented when billing thresholds are active on the subscription or subscription item.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sentence in the description of action parameter in the documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create that seems to explain above case

> action optional - ... If the subscription has billing thresholds, increment is the only allowed value.

Anyway, if this is the case validation error is very misleading.